# Aggregate JSON arrays within table rows / Apply format function to postgres JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres table that contains a `jsonb`-row like this:

| MyTable.refs |
| --- |
| `[{"url": "url1", "name": "name1"}, {"url": "url2", "name": "name2"}]` |
| `[]` |
| `[{"url": "url3", "name": "name3"}` |

I would like to write a postgres function that creates a new column like this:

| result |
| --- |
| `['<a href="url1">name1</a>', '<a href="url2">name2</a>']` |
| `[]` |
| `['<a href="url3">name3</a>'}` |

I already have something:

```
SELECT
       jsonb_agg(format('<a href="%s">%s</a>', (elem ->> 'url'), (elem ->> 'name')))
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[{"url": "url1", "name": "name1"}, {"url": "url2", "name": "name2"}]'::jsonb) elem;
```

Which returns:

```
["<a href="url1">name1</a>", "<a href="url2">name2</a>"]
```

How do I apply this transformation to the whole column?

Comment: That looks like you already have the solution. What exactly is your question then?

Comment: I can only do it on one jsonb element, but am too stupid to apply it to a column/table. I'm sure it's ridiculously easy, so please enlighten me!

Comment: The title should be improved to reflect the actual problem. Maybe "Aggregate JSON arrays within table rows"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for a nested select statement:

```
with mytable (refs) as (
  values
    ('[{"url": "url1", "name": "name1"}, {"url": "url2", "name": "name2"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[]'),
    ('[{"url": "url3", "name": "name3"}]')
)
select (select coalesce(jsonb_agg(format('<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                                         elem->>'url', elem->>'name')),
                        '[]')
        from jsonb_array_elements(refs) elem) result
from mytable;
```

(BTW, `references` is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL which can lead to confusing error messages.)

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem! (I didn't actually use "references" in reality, only for this example. Changed everything to "refs".)